# Spring MVC REST Json Conversion exception

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am following a simple Spring MVC REST example. On PUT request, I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "property" (Class domain.Property), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@75280b93; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: domain.Property["property"]); 
nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:                               
    Unrecognized field "property" (Class domain.Property), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@75280b93; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: domain.Property["property"])
```

I am receiving following JSON

```
{"property":
    {
        "name":"name",
        "age":"22"
    }
}
```

Following is my REST method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Property> updateProperty(@RequestBody Property property,
                                               @PathVariable String id) {   
  final ResponseEntity<Property> response = 
          new ResponseEntity<Property>(property, HttpStatus.OK);
  return response;
}
```

The `Property` is standard POJO with getter/setter for name and age.

How can I resolve this exception?

Comment: Post your "Property" class code too please.

Comment: Your JSON contains a "property" value and property only contains `"name" and "age"` You should remove the property from your JSON. It should only contain  `{ "name":"name", "age":"22" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSON` contains a property named `property` that is not mappable to a `property` field on your `Property` class.  Change the `JSON` to omit this field.  If you cannot change your `JSON` to remove the property `property`, create a wrapper for the `Property` class.

```
class PropertyWrapper(){

    private Property property;

    public Property getProperty(){
       return property;
    }

    public Property setProperty(Property p){
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Then use the `PropertyWrapper` within your controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Property> updateProperty(@RequestBody PropertyWrapper property,
                                               @PathVariable String id) {   
  final ResponseEntity<Property> response = 
          new ResponseEntity<Property>(property.getProperty(), HttpStatus.OK);
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON contains `{"property": { "name":"name", "age":"22" } }`

So the JSON parser searching for a field called `property(setProperty() method exactly)` in the `Property` Class. So you should have a field called `property` with getter and setter in your `Property` Class.

So to ignore any field to parse by JSON which is not in the class, You should annotate the class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

In your class it would be

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Property
```

So it will ignore any field in JSON string which is not in you Property class.

But still your problem wont get solved. Because your JSON string `name and age` is inside **property**. So Basically JSON parser will look for field called `property` (The object of the class). And then inside the object it will set the values of name and age. Then no need to set the JSON ignore property.

**So you have three options**

**1.** Create one object of **Property** called `property` inside the **Property** class with getter and setter

```
public class Property{
    private Property property;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //getter and setter
}
```

And then in your Controller class

```
public ResponseEntity<Property> updateProperty(@RequestBody Property property,
                                               @PathVariable String id) {  

     Property property2=new Property();
     property2=property.getProperty(); 

     //Get Strings from normal object property2

     String name = property2.getName();
     int age = property2,getAge();


  final ResponseEntity<Property> response = 
          new ResponseEntity<Property>(property, HttpStatus.OK);
  return response;
}
```

**2**. To avoid confusion, create another class with a field named **property** as object of `Property`.

*Example:*

```
public class PropertiesJson{
private Property property
//getter and setter
}
```

Then in controller use it instead of Property

```
public ResponseEntity<Property> updateProperty(@RequestBody PropertiesJson propertiesJson,
                                                   @PathVariable String id) {  

         Property property=propertiesJson.getProperty(); 

         //Get Strings from normal object property

         String name = property.getName();
         int age = property.getAge();


      final ResponseEntity<Property> response = 
              new ResponseEntity<Property>(property, HttpStatus.OK);
      return response;
    }
```

**3**. The other option is change your JSON string

```
{ "name":"name", "age":"22" }
```

This is enough. If you can change JSON string, this is better idea. Otherwise, you have to choose any of the other options.

Comment: Thanks Shiju. Your answer is also correct. I marked Kevin reply as answer due to more clear separation.